# Formatting <ol> in a loop

Tags: html, angularjs

I created an HTML script with angular to display the names in an array like follows.

```
 <div ng-repeat="namep in names">
    <li>Name : <span ng-bind="namep.name">      </span></li><br/>
    <li>Age : <span ng-bind="namep.age"></span></li><br/><br/>
 </div>
```

I get the proper output as

```
• John
• 24

• Joe
• 26
```

But I want to format this as

```
 1)
• Name : John
• Age : 24

 2)
• Name : Joe
• Age : 26
```

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ul ng-repeat="namep in names">
   {{$index}}
   <li>Name : {{namep.name}}</li>
   <li>Age : {{namep.age}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That will give me the same Output as i already get, I want to number the people serially as well

Comment: edited my code please check.added $index to show people serially.thanks.

Comment: `<li>` is invalid child of `<div>`

Comment: Ok but now `<p>` is invalid child of `<ul>`

Comment: Got it numbered serially but as its an array , it starts from zero. Anyway to start it from number 1?

Comment: add {{ $index + 1 }}

Comment: @theTechApprentic if it helped you can you please accept and upvote the answer

Comment: Thanks @Kalleshwar

Comment: glad it helped you.Thanks.